# Android TextView change background image when pressed

Tags: android, background, textview

I wanto to change the background-image of a textview when I click it. I have red about the selectors and I did like this:

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img1" /> <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and then in the layout file:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

but it doesn't work. I tried to change the bg color and in this case it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be `img1` matches your background color?

Comment: yes you need to call the set background image at textview insde the oncreat.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal `img1` and `img2` are the same image but with different size

Comment: @sunil i did it but it doesnt't already works! 

`myview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUp); myview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector); myview.setOnClickListener(this);`

i have declared this on `OnCreate()`

Comment: @Rajin: Please use another img2.. as you have mentioned img1 and img2 are same

Comment: @AugustusFrancis the images's names are zoomin48 and zoomin64..i don't think that this is the problem...

Comment: Is the contents same ..

Comment: @AugustusFrancis you're right! i tried with another image and it works. But if i want to show the same image but resized, how can i do?

Comment: I am not sure I get you.. can you post the images here.. the backgrounf images..Resized and Not

Comment: @AugustusFrancis the icons are [here](http://www.iconspedia.com/icon/zoom-in-icon-46214.html), 64x64 and 48x48

Comment: @Rajin See My Answer Below..

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new drawable xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_checked" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_unchecked" /--> 


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_checked" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_checked" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_checked" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_unchecked" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_circle_unchecked" android:state_enabled="true"></item>
</selector>
```

When you create this, you should add in your background attr this xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/addgrnbtnhov"
          android:state_pressed="true" 

          />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/addgrnbtn" /> 
</selector>
```

please use different images.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>


<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/chk"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hello"
  style="@android:style/Widget.TextView"
  android:background="@drawable/selector"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:checked="true"
  android:button="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

```
android:onClick="change"
```

In java:-

```
public void onCLick(View view){
TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUp);
text.setBackgroungResource(R.drawable.image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: sorry but doesn't work. at this point i'll try to change it programmatically, if possible...